# How can I make my JS game of Rock, Paper and Scissors Work?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I need your help to make the game of rock, paper and scissors work for a school assignment. I need your suggestions to help me make this JS game app to work correctly.

The more input from others for this application to work correctly, the better!!

The assignment requires three major things as so:
 * the getchoices function works to acquire
   the input from the user
 * the conditional statement below the 
   variables computer_choice and 
   player_choice that tests for the random
   values the computer generates and 
   does the comparison and then prints out the
   correct value
 * the game works correctly

Thanks for all of the help in advance!

Sean

```js
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

window.onload = function () {
    $("show").onclick = getChoices;
}

compare(player_choice,computer_choice); 

function getChoices() {
    computer_choice = Math.random();
    player_choice = $("player_choice").onclick.value
}    

if(computer_choice <= 0.33 ){
    computer_choice = "Rock";
} else if(computer_choice <= 0.66){
    computer_choice= "Paper";
} else {
    computer_choice = "Scissors";
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
    if(choice1 == choice2){
        return "The result is a tie!";
    } else if(choice1 == "Rock"){
        if(choice2 == "Scissors"){
            return "Rock wins";
        } else {
            return "Paper wins";
        }
    
        if(choice1 == "Paper"){
            if(choice2 == "Rock"){
                return "Paper wins";
            }
        } else{
            return "Scissors wins";
        }
    } else if(choice1 == "Scissors"){
        if(choice2 == "Paper"){
            return "Scissors wins";
        } else{
            return "Rock wins";
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Shipping Order Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script src="assets/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="player_choice">Select either rock, paper or scissors:</label>
      <select name="player_choice" id="player_choice" class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="rock">rock</option>
        <option value="paper">paper</option>
        <option value="scissors">scissors</option>
      </select>
    </div>
 
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Show" name="show" id="show" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*The more input from others [...] the better!!*" is the attitude required for a git project or something. Questions here are designed to target specific problems you have. You have given no details about what is broken, so you are unlikely to find an answer which makes it "work correctly"

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the advice :-) Will definitely heed it if I have anymore questions to submit later to stackoverflow!

Comment: Dear @SeanV, You still haven't defined/marked question as solved. Is there any answer that pleased Your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting makes the code kinda hard to read but some things that I can spot:

```
compare(player_choice,computer_choice);
```

It seems this is called globally in your .js file and will be called once when .js file is loaded, shouldnt this be called after the user makes a choice, e.g. at the end of the getChoices()?:

```
function getChoices() {
  computer_choice = Math.random();
  player_choice = $("player_choice").onclick.value
  compare(player_choice,computer_choice);
}
```

Another obvious error would be that the second part of your compare() function. The formatting makes this kinda hard to spot:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
   if(choice1 == choice2)
   {
       return "The result is a tie!";
   }
   else if(choice1 == "Rock")
   {
       if(choice2 == "Scissors")
       {
           return "Rock wins";
       }
       else 
       {
           return "Paper wins";
       }
      if(choice1 == "Paper")
      {
          if(choice2 == "Rock")
          {
             return "Paper wins";
          }
       }
       else
       {
          return "Scissors wins";
       }
    }
    else if(choice1 == "Scissors")
    {
        if(choice2 == "Paper")
        {
            return "Scissors wins";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Rock wins";
         }
     }
};
```

As you can see it seems you've messed up your brackets a bit. The "if(choice1 == "Paper")" should be an else if on a level above where it is:

```
else if(choice1 == "Rock")
{
   if(choice2 == "Scissors")
   {
       return "Rock wins";
   }
   else 
   {
       return "Paper wins";
   }
}
else if (choice1 == "Paper")
{
  ....
}
else if (choice1 == "Scissors") // this could be an else
{
   ...
}
```

Other than that I would take Wolfies advice to heart, if you learn to format your code and ask a specific question with an explanation of why/what isnt working you are much more likely to get a good answer.

Good luck with your school project though.

PS. The compare() function returns a result-string, you probably want to print that somewhere or set the text of some element to it because as it is now you will return the string but not do anything with the returned value. DS

PSS. player_choice = $("player_choice").onclick.value is probably not what you want to do, it's been a while since I used JQuery but I dont think .onclick.value is even valid? Your probably want something like $("player_choice").value or .selectedValue. You should also be careful of captilizing your options because in your compare function you compare against "Rock" etc but your values in the select-element are called "rock" etc. DSS.

Comment: Feel free to mark one of the answers as correct if you feel they solved your problem.

Comment: My question has been answered by everyone's input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Game versus battle]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v99o2kjp/11/)

```js
var choices = ['scissors', 'rock', 'paper'],
    _game = {},
    gameNo = 0,
    combinations = {
        win: [
            ['rock', 'scissors'],
            ['scissors', 'paper'],
            ['paper', 'rock']
        ]
    },
    wins = {
        cpu: 0,
        player: 0,
        draw: 0
    };

_game.getRandomInt = function (min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};

_game.computerChoice = function () {
    return choices[
        _game.getRandomInt(0, choices.length)
        ];
};

_game.checkCombinations = function (a, b) {
    var playerWin = [a, b],
        winnerBlock = $('div.winner'),
        isPlayerWin = false;

    $('div.player-choice').text(a.toUpperCase());
    $('div.cpu-choice').text(b.toUpperCase());

    if (a === b) {
        wins.draw++;
        return winnerBlock.text('Game #' + gameNo + ' : Draw');
    }

    $.each(combinations.win, function (c, d) {
        if (a == d[0] && b == d[1]) {
            wins.player++;
            return isPlayerWin = true;
        }
    });

    if (!isPlayerWin) {
        wins.cpu++;
    }

    return isPlayerWin ?
        winnerBlock.text('Game #' + gameNo + ' : Player wins') :
        winnerBlock.text('Game #' + gameNo + ' : CPU wins');
};

_game.Play = function (choice) {
    return _game.checkCombinations(
        choice, _game.computerChoice()
    );
};

$('div.choice[data-choice]').click(function () {
    gameNo++;
    _game.Play($(this).data('choice'));

    $.each(wins, function (i, o) {
        $('td[data-winner="' + i + '"]').text(o)
    });

});
```

```css
div.container {
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center;
}

div.choice {
    width: 128px;
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.choice > p {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100% !important;
}

div.choice:hover {
    background: green;
    transition-duration: 1.7s;
}

div.winner {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 4px;
}

div.results {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

div.results table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 468px;
}

div.results table tr td {
    width: 156px !important;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

div.choices div {
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class='choice' data-choice='rock'>
        <img src='http://icons.veryicon.com/png/System/GANT%202/Rock.png'>
        Rock
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class='choice' data-choice='scissors'>
        <img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/124/124818.png'>
        Scissors
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class='choice' data-choice='paper'>
        <img src='http://icons.veryicon.com/png/Game/Larry%20Laffer/Toilet%20Paper.png'>
        Paper
        <br>
    </div>


    <div class='winner'>

    </div>

    <div class="choices">
        <div class="player-choice"></div>
        <div><img src="http://www.whbqt.info/UserFiles/image/versus.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cpu-choice"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="results">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Draws</th>
            <th>CPU</th>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td data-winner="player">0</td>
                <td data-winner="draw">0</td>
                <td data-winner="cpu">0</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Player always wins or draws with rock. This win condition is incorrect: `['rock', 'paper']`. Additionally, rather than helping get OP's code to work, you've substituted a completely different implementation.

Comment: If You want, i can make games statistic below the winning phrase :)

Comment: @J.Titus, kk. Let me re-check

Comment: @J.Titus, usually it's better to give good piece of code, instead of editing mistakes

Comment: @J.Titus years have passed. And still, my solution is better. I have come to that code style (at the exact time point of the year '17) and approach by myself. And it did costed me time. And instead of saying, that I did provide a completely substituted solution had to point out an issue with the author's code style and logic approach. Besides, I can do it even better now. 
We have to teach newbies by a good code, instead of bad, but giving examples of bad code or "how not to write" a code.